# Reduction of orthoesters and acetals with LiAlH4

Tags: organic-reduction

As I know, orthoesters react with $\ce{LiAlH4}$. After searching on the Internet I’ve found that acetals react with $\ce{LiAlH4}$ in the presence of $\ce{AlCl3}$. Why can’t acetals be reduced only in the presence of $\ce{LiAlH4}$, like orthoesters? Why is Lewis acid required for reduction of acetals, but for orthoesters is not? Is it caused by more δ+ on orthoester or there’re other reasons?

Comment: Note, *chemical* information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.

Comment: Where is the polarization of the $\ce{C=O}$ double bond in an acetal, where $\ce{LiAlH4}$, a $\sigma$-nucleophile, may act on?  What would be a good leaving group when they approach for a nucleophilic substitution on an acetal?

Comment: I’m not sure, but I supposed that leaving group, mechanism may be the same as in reduction of orthoesters. What’s the difference between reduction of acetals and orthoesters with LiAlH4, due to which orthoesters react, but acetals don’t?